# How to hide a button or textView while implementing screen recording

Tags: java, android, privacy, screen-recording, information-hiding

Suppose I'm having a screen in which there are many buttons and textViews and if someone who comes through this screen while using the application tries to take a Screenshot or Screen Record, some views shouldn't be captured. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Disabling screenshot functionality in your app is not an option?

Comment: Yes, But I am curious about how people hide few views when screenshots or screen recording features are used

Answer (score -1):

Use file observer with the path to screen shot directory here is a good tutorial
https://theengineerscafe.com/create-fileobserver-android/

Comment: How is this helpful for my question? I see that this is for observing files and I want it for specific views(like a button or textView) in my layout. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Yes i am sorry i had an idea but didm't find time to implement it